# Setting cell values through multiple sheets

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, office-interop

I have a stock ticker I built as a VSTO that grabs the price and then inserts it into a cell in specific worksheets. These sheets are added by a user button press that adds a new sheet, formats it, and then adds its name to the "accountList" sheet (which keeps track of all of these special sheets).

The problem is that it only writes to the newest sheet the user added. Here is a snippet of what's happening during the worksheet loop.

```
foreach (Excel.Worksheet currentWorksheet in Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Worksheets)
            {                    
                tickerRange = currentWorksheet.Range["A6:A1000", Type.Missing]; //location of ticker symbols

                //compare the current worksheet name to any of the names in the accountList
                if (Array.IndexOf(accountList.ToArray(), currentWorksheet.Name) >= 0) { 
                //for every row in the specified range
                foreach (Excel.Range row in tickerRange) //for every row inside the tickerRange variable
                {                        
                    try
                    {
                        quoteCell = row.Offset[0, 5]; //location where market price will be inserted
                        string currentStock = row.Value2; //set ticker Symbol equal to the cell of the range element

                        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentStock) || currentStock.Trim().Length > 4) //if there is nothing in the cell or the length is more than 4 characters, don't call the fetchPrice.
                        {
                             badValue = true;
                        }//end if
                        else if (Regex.IsMatch(currentStock, "[ ]|[0-9]")) //if the cell has whitespace or numbers, don't call fetchPrice. This would result in bad output
                        {
                             badValue = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            currentStock = currentStock.ToUpper();
                        }

                        if (!badValue) //if the dictionary contains the ticker symbol, no need to call fetchPrice again this loop, just get the value out of dictionary
                        {
                            price = tickerDictionary[currentStock];
                            quoteCell.Value2 = price;
                            //volumeCell.Value2 = (stockObject.minuteVolume / stockObject.currentVolume)*100;
                            //break;
                        }
                    } //end try
                    catch (Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException rbe) //i forget why i had to catch this in the first place. but it came up once, and now it's caught. so there's that. 
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Runtime Binder Exception caught");
                    }//end catch
                    catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException ce)
                    {
                        stopTicker();
                    }
                } //end 'row' foreach
            } //end 'sheet' foreach
```

Watching the local variables during debug I can see the accountList is populated with the correct info, and the foreach loops are hitting my other worksheets, but `quoteCell.Value2 = price` does not update the price on any other worksheet other than my newest.

Am I missing something silly here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the problem using [this link here](https://chrismemo.wordpress.com/2013/12/04/common-mistakes-when-programming-excel-with-c/), which cautions against using foreach's over COM objects, as their index accessors are unreliable.

After switching a few things around, and replacing my foreach's with good ol' fashioned for loops, i'm in business. Here is the updated code:

```
 Sheets worksheets = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets;
            int wsCount = worksheets.Count;
            for (int w = 1; w <= wsCount; w++)
            {                    
                Worksheet currentWorksheet = worksheets.Item[w] as Worksheet;                       
                    string mysheet = currentWorksheet.Name;                    
                    tickerRange = null;
                    tickerRange = currentWorksheet.Range["A6:A1000", Type.Missing]; //location of ticker symbols
                    if (Array.IndexOf(accountList.ToArray(), mysheet) >= 0)
                    {
                        //for every row in the specified range
                        //foreach (Range row in currentWorksheet.Range["A6:A1000", Type.Missing]) //for every row inside the tickerRange variable
                        for (int r = 6; r <=1000; r++)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                badValue = false;
                                Range row = null;
                                row = currentWorksheet.Range["A" + r];                                    
                                quoteCell = null;
                                //quoteCell = currentWorksheet.Range["A6:A1000", Type.Missing];
                                //quoteCell = quoteCell.Range[row.Offset[0, 5], Type.Missing];
                                quoteCell = row.Offset[0, 5]; //location where market price will be inserted
                                string currentStock = row.Value2; //set ticker Symbol equal to the cell of the range element                            
                                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentStock) || currentStock.Trim().Length > 4) //if there is nothing in the cell or the length is more than 4 characters, don't call the fetchPrice.
                                {
                                    badValue = true;
                                }//end if
                                else if (Regex.IsMatch(currentStock, "[ ]|[0-9]")) //if the cell has whitespace or numbers, don't call fetchPrice. This would result in bad output
                                {
                                    badValue = true;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    currentStock = currentStock.ToUpper();
                                }

                                if (!badValue) //if the dictionary contains the ticker symbol, no need to call fetchPrice again this loop, just get the value out of dictionary
                                {
                                    price = tickerDictionary[currentStock];
                                    quoteCell.Value2 = price;
                                    //volumeCell.Value2 = (stockObject.minuteVolume / stockObject.currentVolume)*100;
                                    //break;
                                }
                            } //end try
                            catch (Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException rbe) //i forget why i had to catch this in the first place. but it came up once, and now it's caught. so there's that. 
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Runtime Binder Exception caught");
                            }//end catch
                            catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException ce)
                            {
                                stopTicker();
                            }
                            /*if a KeyNotFound exception was thrown, it was because the user entered a new stock symbol while the loop was running, but
                            AFTER assemblePrice() was called. This results in the dictionary being asked for something it doesn't have. Just run assemblePrice() again. 
                            */
                            catch (System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException knfe) 
                            {                                
                            assemblePrice(); 
                            }
                        } //end for
                    }

                Console.WriteLine("For Loop Completed");
                Console.WriteLine("Sleep Started for " + restartTime + "seconds");
                //if the timerbox is empty, is set to 5 or less, or contains non-numeric characters
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(timerBox.Text) || Regex.Equals(timerBox.Text, "[0-5]") || Regex.IsMatch(timerBox.Text, "[^0-9]"))
                {
                    restartTime = 10;
                }//end else
                else
                {
                    restartTime = Convert.ToInt32(timerBox.Text); //restartTime gets the value after string contents of timerBox are cast to int.
                }//end else
            }//bigger for loop done
```

Comment: No idea what the article you refer to is talking about. This work just fine for me: `For Each MyCell As Excel.Range In Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection:MyCell.Value2 = "x":Next`

Comment: What resolved your problem is `row = ` **currentWorksheet** `.Range["A" + r];`. See my updated answer for a full understanding.

Comment: Apologies I got quite confused with VBA. I just switched recently and was so used to VBA I never realised I did not need to refer to the Worksheet Name anymore (what a discovery.. !). So my comment and proposed answer were both wrong. However, For Each does work with VSTO, I use it all the time. Not sure what is wrong with your code then...

Comment: No worries. This is the first time I've run into this issue and was quite surprised. Also, this activity is taking place on a background thread, so it's also a possible culprit of not playing nicely with COM.